# How can I Setup overloaded method invocations in Moq?

Tags: c#, moq, overloading

I'm trying to mock a mapping interface `IMapper`:

```
public interface IMapper<TFoo, TBar> {
    TBar Map(TFoo foo);
    TFoo Map(TBar bar);
}
```

In my test, I'm setting the mock mapper up to expect an invocation of each (around an NHibernate `update` operation):

```
//...
_mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map(fooMock.Object)).Returns(barMock.Object);
_mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map(barMock.Object)).Returns(fooMock.Object);
//...
```

However, when the second `Map` invocation is made, the mapper mock throws because it is only expecting a single invocation.

Watching the mapper mock during setup at runtime, I can look see the `Map(TFoo foo)` overload get registered, and then see it get replaced when the `Map(TBar bar)` overload is set up.

Is this a problem with the way Moq handles setup, or is there a different syntax I need to use in this case?

**EDIT**
Here is the actual instantiation code from the test constructor:

```
public class TestClass {
    private readonly MockRepository _repository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);

    public TestClass() {
        //...
        _mapperMock = _repository.Create
            <IMapper<RequestData.Foo, ResponseData.Bar>>();
        //...
     }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is a complete failing test case:

```
public interface IMapper<TFoo, TBar> {
    TFoo Map(TBar bar);
    TBar Map(TFoo foo);
}

public class Foo {
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        // return base.GetHashCode();
        return 1;
    }
}

public class Bar {
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        // return base.GetHashCode();
        return 2;
    }
}

[Test]
public void TestIt()
{
    // Arrange
    var _mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper<Foo, Bar>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var fooMock = new Mock<Foo>();
    var barMock = new Mock<Bar>();

    _mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map(fooMock.Object)).Returns(barMock.Object);
    _mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map(barMock.Object)).Returns(fooMock.Object);

    // Act - breaks on first line below this comment
    var bar = _mapperMock.Object.Map(fooMock.Object);
    var foo = _mapperMock.Object.Map(barMock.Object);

    // Assert
    _mapperMock.Verify(x => x.Map(fooMock.Object), Times.Once());
    _mapperMock.Verify(x => x.Map(barMock.Object), Times.Once());
}
```

If I comment out the `GetHashCode()` override on either `Foo` or `Bar`, or on both, the test case passes.  Or, if I don't use `Mock`s of `Foo` and `Bar`, the test case passes.

**EDIT 3**
I opened [Moq Issue 347](http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=347) against this problem, with more detailed test cases.

Comment: Can you please include your code where you are instantiating _mapperMock?  Thanks.

Comment: The only time I can see your above code failing is if the generic TFoo and TBar are the same type.  E.g. var _mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper<TypeA, TypeA>>();  If they are different (e.g. var _mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper<TypeA, TypeB>>();), it should work

Comment: They are different types, inheriting from different subtypes.  I can see the method resolution varying correctly when I step through the test in the debugger, but the first invocation is simply replaced by the second when the second `Setup` call is made.  I'll add the actual instantiation code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your `Foo` and `Bar` classes look like, but this test passes for me (Moq 4.0.10827.0, which is the newest one in NuGet)

```
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestIt()
        {
            // Arrange
            var _mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper<Foo, Bar>>();
            var fooMock = new Mock<Foo>();
            var barMock = new Mock<Bar>();

            _mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map(fooMock.Object)).Returns(barMock.Object);
            _mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map(barMock.Object)).Returns(fooMock.Object);

            // Act
            var bar = _mapperMock.Object.Map(fooMock.Object);
            var foo = _mapperMock.Object.Map(barMock.Object);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreSame(bar, barMock.Object);
            Assert.AreSame(foo, fooMock.Object);

            _mapperMock.Verify(x => x.Map(fooMock.Object), Times.Once());
            _mapperMock.Verify(x => x.Map(barMock.Object), Times.Once());
        }
    }

    public class Bar
    {
    }

    public class Foo
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The default behavior for your mock would be `Loose`.  Does the test above still pass if `_mapperMock` uses `Strict` behavior?

Comment: I tested the above with `var _mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper<Foo, Bar>>(MockBehavior.Strict);` and it does still pass.

Comment: Interesting...I wonder if it has something to do with using the `MockRepository` to define the mapper.  I'll try directly instantiating `_mapperMock` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Still breaking in my case with the DLL from the website (we are otherwise using a copy built from source AFAICT), and using a locally instantiated mock of the mapper.  However, I've discovered that it has *something* to do with the base classes that underlie `Foo` and `Bar` - if I run the test without the base classes specified, it will pass, but if I specify that `Foo` and `Bar` extend the respective base classes, the test fails.

Comment: Con you post the code for `Foo` and `Bar` and their base types that make it fail?

Comment: I distilled the base type to what causes the failure, and posted the complete code as an edit.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it led to my further investigation, and because I ripped off your code for the test case :P